# ipython notebook server setup debug

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

I'm trying to set up an [ipython notebook server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html) on an Ubuntu host machine - but can't seem to access it remotely. I set up the notebook server as per the tutorial, and launch it - everything seems fine. But going to `https://my-host-ip:9999/` I get a timeout (`error 118`) message in the browser.

My intuition is that need to open the appropriate port (`9999` in the setup tutorial) on my host. How do I do this (safely) with Ubuntu? More generally, is there a debugging checklist I should go through at this point?

Comment: similar question for OSX [here](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/IPython-User-Help-troubleshooting-notebook-as-public-server-td3289467.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run it as public ? (listening on '*' ?)

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html#running-a-public-notebook-server

Don't forget to make it over https and with password.

Answer (score 0):

- Is the port 9999 open?
- I don't know why, but I had to set the IP to the IP of host to make it work.